# Ubi Partman error with exit code 141 while installing Kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, kubuntu

I'm trying to install Kubuntu by making a partition in my SSD with Universal USB tool. But it gives error `ubi-partman failed with exit code 141`.

I've disable fast boot and secure boot, and changed to AHCI from Raid in BIOS, also tried disabling BIOS but nothing seems to work. Also tried making free space formatted in exFAT.

When I try to install other OS like Ubuntu and Linux mint they seem to install correctly without any error.

I cannot wipe my full SSD as I don't have a backup SSD to store data. And neither I have USB flash drive, that's why I'm making a 5gb partition in SSD to install Kubuntu from.

Comment: Here's one instruction vid that might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7Kp6wmfRvw. If not, I'd re-download the ISO file and test creating the installer with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie).

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me I'm using windows 11 though but still can't find the solution. I did find a different way to run kubuntu

1. first install the default Ubuntu with that gnome desktop environment
2. after installation download kde  desktop environment in the terminal
3. finish the process and then change the desktop environment in the login menu
4. now you can use kde , I don't know much about Linux i just wanted to try it this helped me with this case

Answer (score 0):

I was having this trouble until I found [this article on dell.com](https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/linux-general/15-r4-ubuntu-install-disable-irst/647f8979f4ccf8a8de915050), explaining that the disk controller mode had to be changed from RST (Rapid Storage Tech) to AHCI.

This happened to me on a Dell 15 XPS that had ALREADY had Kubuntu 22.04 installed on it, but I had not turned it on in awhile (battery went dead, clock had to be reset, etc).  So, my guess is that the BIOS setting had already been set to AHCI during my initial install, and when the NVRAM got reset due to low batter, the setting went back to RST.  It's in the BIOS (accessible via F12).

The good news is that once I changed the setting from RST to AHCI, the machine booted into Kubuntu immediately, and I did NOT have to re-install Kubuntu.